# Audiodecoding fails for AWS Predictions speech to text

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to record audio in my browser and transcribe it to text using the AWS Transcription service. My setup works for the first request by fails, because the AudioContext can't decode the following audio segments.

My Vue setup:

```js
    // initialize refs
    const isRecording = ref(false)
    const device = ref(null)
    const recorder = ref(null)

    async function recordAudio() {
      // set recording state
      isRecording.value = true
      device.value = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
      await device.value.then((stream) => {
        // create recorder
        recorder.value = new MediaRecorder(stream)
        recorder.value.ondataavailable = async (e) => {
          await convertAudio(e.data)
        }
      })
      // start with interval
      recorder.value.start(500)
    }

    // called on stop-button click
    async function stop() {
      recorder.value.stop()
      // reset recording state
      isRecording.value = false
    }

    async function convertAudio(data) {
      const audioBuffer = await new Response(data).arrayBuffer()
      const context = new AudioContext()
      context.decodeAudioData(audioBuffer, async (res) => {
        let output = res.getChannelData(0)
        console.log(output)
        await Predictions.convert({
          transcription: {
            source: {
              bytes: output
            },
            language: 'de-DE'
          }
        })
          .then(({ transcription: { fullText } }) => console.log({ fullText }))
          .catch((err) => console.log({ err }))
      })
    }
  }
```

After the first audio decoding I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'decodeAudioData' on 'BaseAudioContext': Unable to decode audio data"